# Android: Resuming an activity without reloading

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities, say `Activity A` and `Activity B`.
`Activity A` is created when the application starts and then `Activity B` is being called from `Activity A` as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
```

`Activity B` loads a `Thread` on its `onCreate()` and then when you click on `Back`, it will return to `Activity A`. This `Thread` is loading some images from a `Database` that is being updated within `Activity B` as well.

How can I save the state of `Activity B` so that I can avoid reloading the `Thread` that I have in `Activity B` when I call it again from `Activity A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a singleton class which loads the images and caches them. Every time you launch `Activity B` check this singleton class for images. If not loaded then load them otherwise read from the cache

Comment: Thanks for the advice, can you show me some samples of a singleton class?

Comment: see this link for example of singleton class http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=31650   move your loading thread in the constructor of this class

Answer (score 0):

Move the database loading to a separate class and load from there.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this question: [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

But consider that, depending on how long the Activity A takes and how much memory the device has left, Activity B could be killed before it returns.

Comment: I have actually read that a while ago and tried implementing it but i got no luck.. :(

Comment: It seems that onSaveInstanceState() on Activity B is not being called. I think this is what this link:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29 is trying to explain.